# vs code insiders arm64 "extension host terminated unexpectedly" on m1 macbook

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, apple-m1

Today I've installed the native version of vs code insiders on my m1 macbook for the first time.
Every time I open vs code I get this message: "extension host terminated unexpectedly".
I've disabled all extensions to check which one gave me this error and found out that 50% of my extension gave me this error.

Is there a way to fix this? Do anybody managed to install the arm64 version of vs code with extensions on the new m1 mac?

Please tell me if you need more information.

(I've installed many tools via terminal through rosetta)

[image]

Comment: This should probably be asked in the vscode Github issue tracker, since this seems to affect a large number of extension. I'm not sure vscode is already ready for the M1 CPU, so it's probably running in Rosetta2.

Answer (score 2):

See the following issue on GitHub. An update is on the way, but there is a workaround for now.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113680